# How to import module installed in home directory?

Tags: python, unix, module, package, pip

I installed Python3.4.3 in my home directory so it is under `/home/jdoe/.local/bin/python3` and I pip installed some external modules to this by doing `pip install --user package_name`. However now when writing my python script the package python looks for is not found because it is looking in the `usr/lib` but the package is not there. How can I import a module so python looks at the site-packages installed in my personal home directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append the path to your path variable

```
import sys
sys.path.append("<path>")
```

However are you sure that your `pip install --user` actually installed a python3.4 package, usually one does not need to add any paths to the path for pip installed packages?

What is the output of `pip --version`

Comment: well specifically i installed with `/home/jdoe/.local/bin/python3.4 -m pip install --user package_name`

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [this tutorial](http://www.mantidproject.org/Using_Modules), there are basically 2 options: use `PYTHONPATH` or `sys.append`.

[`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) is an environment variable used to extend the directories where Python searches for modules. It can be set in the command line before running python:

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:<Path to Module>
$ python
```

Or adding the line `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:<Path to Module>` in the bash configuration file (i.e. `.bashrc`). If it is set in the `.bashrc`, then all python scripts executed in the computer will search for modules there.

`sys.append` is called from within Python. And it can be added at the beginning of a file that calls the module or called from the Python interpreter with the following lines:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('<Path to Module>')
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say I have a script that falls under `$HOME/repo/code/sample.py` and I want to import it into `$HOME/repo2/code/sample.py` one way to do it is:

```
import os 
import sys 
env=os.path.expanduser(os.path.expandvars($HOME/repo) # "source" directory with python script
sys.path.insert(0, env)
import code.sample
```

This will remove the dependency to `export PYTHONPATH`, and allow you to easily import between files/folders as if they are any other module.